# Admob ads do not work on Google App Stores Version of my Application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I made my first Android game and uploaded it to the Google app store. I've used Admob to advertise in my game. Before uploading, I tested the game (both in debug mode and with signed builds), and ads were working as expected. But after downloading the game from the app store, the ads stopped working.

Is this normal for me to not see the ads?

I have asked several friends from different countries and have found that they can not see the ads either.

Comment: when you upload apk in play console you see check mark  of "app contains add" ?

Comment: yes, and i check it,

Comment: so you still not getting ads in your app?

Comment: yes :( , same problem